# Android: How to provide custom path to google-services.json using sourceSets?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

Is there a way to specify path to google-services.json using sourceSets?

I've tried something like this, but with no success

```
productFlavors {
        apple {
            dimension "fruit"
        }
        juice {
            dimension "beverage"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        appleJuice {
            res.srcDirs = ["src/apple/juice/google-services.json"]
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  The logic to find the config file is baked into the plugin as described in the documentation. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file